# passing value from between each pipe

Tags: powershell

i was able to print out the final result from my if..elseif..else as below:

```
clear-host
$errorCode = 0
$object = "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName"
$logfile = "C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv"
$oldFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book1.csv"
$newFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book2.csv"
if ((Test-Path $oldFile) -And (Test-Path $newFile)) {
    $impFileOld = Import-Csv $oldFile -Header $object | Sort-object -Property $object -unique 
    $impFileNew = Import-Csv $newFile -Header $object | Sort-object -Property $object -unique 
    $result = Compare-Object $impFileOld $impFileNew -Property $object -PassThru
    $result | %{if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {write-host "book2"} #show result
        elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=') {write-host "book1"}
            else {Add-Content $logfile "no changes found."
                    #$errorCode = 0    
                }
            }
    } else {
            Add-Content $logfile "files does not exist!"
            #$errorCode = 1            
            exit 1
};
```

But when i substitute it with the select-object and write the final result to another .cvs file, it seem that there is 'lost of connection' or passing of the infor: please below code:

```
clear-host
$errorCode = 0
$object = "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName"
$logfile = "C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv"
$oldFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book1.csv"
$newFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book2.csv"
if ((Test-Path $oldFile) -And (Test-Path $newFile)) {
    $impFileOld = Import-Csv $oldFile -Header $object | Sort-object -Property $object -unique 
    $impFileNew = Import-Csv $newFile -Header $object | Sort-object -Property $object -unique 
    $result = Compare-Object $impFileOld $impFileNew -Property $object -PassThru
    $result | %{if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {Select-Object $object | export-csv $logfile -NoTypeInfo} #cannot print result to .csv file  ????
        elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=') {Select-Object $object | export-csv $logfile -NoTypeInfo} 
            else {Add-Content $logfile "no changes found."
                    #$errorCode = 0    
                }
            }
    } else {
            Add-Content $logfile "files does not exist!"
            #$errorCode = 1            
            exit 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have multiple problems, without offence you.

1. You can't do a select like you do into foreach (% in your code)
2. Not necessary to test Sideindicator because you log always in the same file and you dont have use -IncludeEqual option into compare command
3. You test if not change its not really correct
4. -Passthru option is not necessary
5. Sort is not necessary after import-csv because compare command compare field by field
6. You can simplify your code for better lisibility

if propose you a simplify version :

```
cls
$object = "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName"
$logfile = "C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv"
$oldFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book1.csv"
$newFile = "C:\temp\cep\Book2.csv"

if (!(Test-Path $oldFile) -Or !(Test-Path $newFile)) 
{
    Add-Content $logfile "files does not exist!"
    exit 1
}

$impFileOld = Import-Csv $oldFile -Header $object 
$impFileNew = Import-Csv $newFile -Header $object 
$result = Compare $impFileOld $impFileNew -Property $object

if ($result -eq $null)
{
    Add-Content $logfile "no changes found." 
}
else
{
   $result | where SideIndicator -eq '=>' | select $object | sort $object | export-csv "C:\temp\cep\gogoBook2.csv" -NoType
   $result | where SideIndicator -eq '<=' | select $object | sort $object | export-csv "C:\temp\cep\gogoBook1.csv" -NoType
}
```

Comment: without the sideindicator how to find out the diff is from book1 or book2 ? i actually intend to output it into difference .cvs naming meaning if '=>' output as gogo1.csv , if '<=" then gogo2.cvs else nochange to gogo.csv

Comment: if ($result.SideIndicator -eq '=>')
{
    $result | select $object | sort $object | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogoBook2.csv -NoType
}
elseif ($result.SideIndicator -eq '<=')  # this seem to work 
{
    $result | select $object | sort $object | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogoBook1.csv -NoType
}
else
{
 Add-Content $logfile "No Changes"
}

Comment: Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "SideIndicator" value of type "System.String" t
o type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:7 char:19
+    $result | where <<<<  SideIndicator -eq '=>' | select $object | sort $object | export-csv "C:\temp\cep\gogoBook2.c
sv" -NoType
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: what is your PowerShell version? try to modify like this : where { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}

Comment: urs suggestion to where ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} works But the if elseif else condition helps me to only determine with 1 output final then to product 2 files cos u have '=>' & '<=' together in the else {} statement. see below for the code i tried to modified

Comment: if ($result.SideIndicator -eq '=>')
{
    $result | select $object | sort $object | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogoBook2.csv -NoType
}
elseif ($result.SideIndicator -eq '<=')
{
    $result | select $object | sort $object | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogoBook1.csv -NoType
}
else
{
 Add-Content $logfile "No Changes"
}

Comment: i think your result is the same :)